# Express 4: How to catch param in dynamic route structured like file name?

Tags: node.js, regex, express, url, url-routing

I'm trying to use Express 4 route endpoint that has part of the route in the file URL part - file name. It's used for dynamic generated image. I think it's best described by example...

---

#### What I have right now

Right now I have something like this in my routes:

`app.get('/api/listing/:id/cover.png', viewListingImage)`

And e.g. this URL `http://localhost:9500/api/listing/750/cover.png` matches listing with id 750.

#### Expectations

What I would like to have is URL which last part is a filename with listing id in it. So I can quickly save it locally with that filename. E.g.

`http://localhost:9540/api/listing/750-cover.png`

So basically, I'd like to just replace forward slash with a hyphen.

---

Tried some RegEx magic, but had not luck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also make a route for `/api/listing/:filename` and then just use your own Javascript in the route handler to parse out the two pieces of your filename to end up with both the `750` and the `cover.png`.  I would not suggest doing this is you also have routes that do something different that use a different base filename.  That's kind of breaking with core REST principles to bury a parameter in a filename.

Comment: It feels a bit to me like what you really want is URLs like this: `http://localhost:9540/api/listing/cover.png?id=750` since the route is `/api/listing/cover.png` and the parameter id `id=750`.  Then, you would use `req.query.id` to access the id value.

Comment: @jfriend00 The service/endpoint is mainly consumed privately and I don't aim it to be RESTful. And as for the second solution - if I'll want to quicky drag and drop this image from browser to OS to save it then I'll still end up with cover.png instead 750-cover.png, and this is my main problem. 

But it seems like your solution in first comment will work for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex in the route:

```
const app = require('express')();

// match /api/listing/ddd-filename
// where ddd is a series of digits
app.get(/\/api\/listing\/(\d+)-([^\/]+)/, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(80);
```

Then, if you request a URL such as `/api/listing/20-cover.png`, you will find that in the request handler:

```
req.params[0] === '20'
req.params[1] === 'cover.png';
```

Capture groups in the regex are put into req.params as described [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params).

---

As I said in my comments, you could also just do:

```
app.get('/api/listing/:filename', function(req, res) {
    // parse req.params.filename yourself here
});
```